# The editText field does not respond in a pop up window android

Tags: android, android-edittext, popup

I am trying to implement an edit text field on a pop up windows, but do not get any focus when I click on it.

this is the pop up layout

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/rl_custom_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:padding="2dp"
    android:background="#ab2fc4"
    >
    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/ib_close"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_baseline_close_24"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:background="@null"
        />
    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/tv"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="This is a sample popup window."
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:padding="25sp"
        />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Any help would be greta thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I created a sample project with your layout and it seems that your layout is just fine.
Maybe the problem is how you create the pop up.
Here is the code to show a pop up window and the import is 
`import androidx.appcompat.app.AlertDialog`.

```
fun simplePopupMessage(context: Context): AlertDialog {
        val mBuilder = AlertDialog.Builder(context)
        val mView = View.inflate(context, R.layout.pop_up, null)
        val alertDialog = mBuilder.setView(mView).create()

        alertDialog.show()
        return alertDialog
    }
```

Just a friendly recommendation... Instead of RelativeLayout use ConstraintLayout.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I will try it